# Multithreading - Interrupt Thread upon WinForms Event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm working on a C# WinForms project which implements a password manager.  One of the features I want to include is a timeout for how long a password is allowed to stay in the system clipboard.  I implemented a thread which updates a progress bar & then clears the clipboard before the thread terminates:

```
private void getPassword(int lifeInSeconds)
    {
        int maxLifeBarValue = lifeInSeconds * 10;

        Thread t = new Thread
        (delegate ()
        {
            //Initialize the progress bar
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lifeBar.Maximum = maxLifeBarValue;
                lifeBar.Value = maxLifeBarValue;
                lifeBar.Visible = true;
                Clipboard.SetText(pd.getAccountPassword(lstAccounts.Text));
            });

            //Loop to update the progress bar
            for (int x = maxLifeBarValue; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    lifeBar.Value = x;
                });
            }

            //Clear the system clipboard
            Clipboard.SetText(string.Empty);

            //Hide the progress bar when we're done
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lifeBar.Visible = false;
            });
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

This works, but the problem I'm having is that if the user triggers an event to copy another password (or the same one; it doesn't matter), we now have 2 threads running in the background.  This is apparent by the fact that the progress bar is "flipping out" so to speak as each thread is updating it's value independently.

Is there a way in which I can detect & terminate the original thread (if it exists) when the user clicks the copy password button again?

Comment: In your `for (int x = maxLifeBarValue; x >= 0; x--)` loop, check a `hasBeenCanceled` flag (that would be set from the UI thread).  If it was canceled, set the visibility to false and exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a reference to the Thread, and then abort the thread before starting a new one.  Like this:

```
private Thread passwordClearThread = null;

private void getPassword(int lifeInSeconds)
{
  int maxLifeBarValue = lifeInSeconds * 10;

  if (passwordClearThread != null && passwordClearThread.IsAlive)
  {
    passwordClearThread.Abort();
    passwordClearThread.Join();
  }

  passwordClearThread = new Thread
  (() =>
  {
    //Initialize the progress bar
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      lifeBar.Maximum = maxLifeBarValue;
      lifeBar.Value = maxLifeBarValue;
      lifeBar.Visible = true;
      Clipboard.SetText(pd.getAccountPassword(lstAccounts.Text));
    });

    //Loop to update the progress bar
    for (int x = maxLifeBarValue; x >= 0; x--)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
      {
        lifeBar.Value = x;
      });
    }

    //Clear the system clipboard
    Clipboard.Clear();

    //Hide the progress bar when we're done
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      lifeBar.Visible = false;
    });
  });
  passwordClearThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  passwordClearThread.Start();
}
```